# Excel, How to count keywords between dates

Tags: excel, date, count, keyword

In excel, I am looking for a way to count keywords between specific dates.

In column A, I have bunch of sentences that are mentioned in corresponding dates in column B.

### For example,

| Sentences | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Apple is delicious | 4/1/2021 |
| Banana is delicious | 4/1/2021 |
| Grape is delicious | 4/1/2021 |
| Apple is delicious | 4/1/2021 |
| Banana is delicious | 4/2/2021 |
| Orange is delicious | 4/3/2021 |
| Banana is delicious | 4/3/2021 |

I have tried using =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("tsla",A2:A8)))) but I know it's wrong since there are different number of rows for each date.

As a result, I am looking for on this date, this keyword was mentioned n times and this keyword was mentioned n times and so forth.

Please look at attached image for example.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpqsA.png)
[image]

Comment: In your image they are not actual date but just string. I also do not find any word `tsla` what you are trying to count.

Comment: You have a fake date in column E of your example. This formula will create a true date: [E2] `=DATE(D2,B2, C2)`. The date will be displayed in your computer's default short date format. use the cell format to change the display.

Answer (score 0):

From your given example to post you can try below formula if you have `Excel365`.

```
=SUM(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$1,FILTER($A$2:$A$8,($B$2:$B$8>=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$8<=$E$2))))))
```

You can also use `SUMPRODUCT()` in this way.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8>=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$8<=$E$2)*(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$1,$A$2:$A$8))))
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know! Then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it) so that visitors can know it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As some users have posted in the comments, first of all you should make sure your dates are being recognized as dates. By default, Excel aligns numbers to right and strings to right, so your dates are not being recognized as dates.

You should do `=DATE(D2,C2, B2)`

Also, based on your data example, you can count how many cells containg specific words with COUNTIFS and wildcards.

[image]

My formula in H3 is:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8;">="&$E$2;$B$2:$B$8;"<="&$F$2;$A$2:$A$8;"*"&G3&"*")
```